# Information on Entity Class

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, entity

I have a Student table with Columns name, age, gender and address.
Is it possible to create a Java POJO class with `@Entity` annotation and
have only name and address in it?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Student")
public class Student {

  @Column(name = "name")
  String name;

  @Column(name="address")
  String address;
}
```

I am new to Spring boot and searched a bit around this but couldn't get any specific answer.

Comment: have you tried?

Comment: Yes, got the exception as org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] (conn=4760) Unknown column 'student_.age' in 'field list'

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Even if possible, how will you insert/update data in those columns then? If you need to send partial data in some response, then use dtos or projections.

Comment: I will add explicit select and update queries. I want to avoid a param(holds xml) to get loaded to memory while fetching data from the table.

Comment: In general it's allowed. Would need your complete code to reproduce the issue.